# Permutation parsing with `ParsecT`?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, parsec, parser-combinators

I have a file parser that uses `permute` from [`parsec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) to combine various `Parser`s. It looks like `permute` only allows the `Identity` monad, which I'm sure cuts down on the algorithmic complexity.

Now I'm trying to convert all of my parsing code to use `MyErrorClass m => ParsecT String () m`, where `Monad m => MyErrorClass m` is a `class` with special error handling. Specifically, the code that uses `permute` now needs to combine parsers that require `MyErrorClass m` so that they can provide structured errors rather than just using `fail`. (`permute` is used only when parsing module config files for a programming language. The file format allows embedding of some language constructs, reusing parsers from the compiler.)

I only use `permute` in 3 places and that number isn't likely to increase, so it isn't out of the question to hack together some sort of one-off function for each of the 3. Alternatively, I can just remove the flexibility in field ordering, but I'd rather not.

---

Before I do anything major, am I missing a simple solution in `parsec`? Maybe I can somehow stuff `ParsecT String () m` into `permute` from [`parsers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsers) as opposed to `parsec`? (This would add a dependency, but might be worth it.)

---

**Edit:**

Here is some background regarding why structured errors are useful for parsing.

For the most part, I do parsing and validation separately. For example, checking for duplicate symbol definitions happens after parsing succeeds.

I frequently get parsing errors similar to `expected //, /* or argument type`, and it can take a while (for me, the language creator) to understand what parser is being invoked.

`MyErrorClass` allows structuring of error messages, e.g.

```
("In parsing of function declaration for " ++ show f) ??> do
  -- parse the components of function f
  -- any error messages here will be nested under the message above
```

Being able to add context like this will at least tell the user what the parser was trying to do at the time of failure.

Lastly, using `MyErrorClass` will also allow fail-fast errors that cannot be suppressed by `try` or `<|>`. (In a few places I have explicit error messages for using obsolete syntax.)

Comment: Perhaps `Control.Applicative.Permutations` from "parser-combinators" could be an option. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parser-combinators-1.2.1/docs/Control-Applicative-Permutations.html

Comment: In general, it’s advisable to parse a superset of the language you actually accept, so you can provide more useful error messages, and to decouple parsing from validation. So my preferred approach to parsing permutation-like things is to 1. parse a sequence of items and then verify that the result is a permutation (and if not, you can easily report *how*); or 2. use a stateful parser, keeping all the permutation alternatives as a container of separate parsers, and removing each one that matches until either the container is empty (accept) or none of them matches (reject).

Comment: @JonPurdy Thanks for the suggestion. I added some notes regarding that. tl;dr: I want to be able to add nested context for parsing failures, such as the overall object type being parsed.

Comment: @danidiaz Thanks for the suggestion. That looks like a better option than `parsers`, since it has only `base` as a dependency.

Comment: @JonPurdy Regarding permutations as alternatives, I'm not sure how that can be done cleanly for heterogeneous types. I could certainly create an n-tuple of `Maybe`s, but that doesn't scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @danidiaz suggested, [`parser-combinators`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parser-combinators) easily solves the *literal* problem of permuting `ParsecT`.

The caveat is that using `ParsecT` with a `Monad m` that *transforms* errors (even its own) isn't particularly useful, other than being able to use fail-fast errors that can't be ignored by `<|>` and `try`.

- You can't "demote" the error state of the `ParsecT` to `m`'s own type of error because (AFAIK) there is no way to access the current error state of the `ParsecT`.
- `ParsecT` lacks something comparable to `StateT`'s `mapStateT`. This means that there is no way to transform an error stored in `m` without actually executing the parser with `runPT` (etc.), which isn't possible to do mid-parse.

In summary, `ParsecT` doesn't leak `m` in the same way that `StateT` does, making some of `m`'s functionality inaccessible from within `ParsecT`.

Comment: The "megaparsec" library has baked-in support for user-defined errors, and it also seems to have a way to "map" errors: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.0.1/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#v:region A tutorial: https://markkarpov.com/tutorial/megaparsec.html

Comment: @danidiaz Thanks, I'll take a look!

Comment: @danidiaz It looks like `megaparsec` keeps the error state separate from the `Monad` it transforms. I think I could still work with that by creating a new `instance` for my error-tracking `class`.